Swift async Loop in Task
I trying to understand how exactly Task works with loop.
I was experimenting with outputting numbers to the console and noticed that I was getting a result that was not what I expected.
actor ThreadSafeCollection<T> {
    private var collection: [T] = []

    func add(_ element: T) {
        collection.append(element)
    }

    func getAll() -> [T] {
        return collection
    }

    func remove(at index: Int) {
        guard collection.indices.contains(index) else { return }
        collection.remove(at: index)
    }
}

var safeCollection: ThreadSafeCollection<Int> = ThreadSafeCollection()

@Sendable func firstIterate() async -> Task<[Int], Never> {
    Task {
        for i in 0..<500 {
            await safeCollection.add(i)
        }
        return await safeCollection.getAll()
    }
}

@Sendable func secondIterate() async -> Task<[Int], Never> {
    Task {
        for i in 0..<500 {
            await safeCollection.add(i)
        }
        return await safeCollection.getAll()
    }
}

Task {
    let result = await withTaskGroup(of: [Int].self, returning: [Int].self) { taskGroup in
        taskGroup.addTask { await firstIterate().value }
        taskGroup.addTask { await secondIterate().value }
        
        var collected = [Int]()
        
        for await value in taskGroup {
            collected.append(contentsOf: value)
        }

        return collected
    }
    print(result.sorted(by: <))
}



In this example, I iterate 2 times to 500 by calling the first Iterate() and secondIterate() methods, as a result of which I expect to get an array with numbers in which each number will be repeated 2 times. But instead, I see each number 4 times in the console.
[0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 3, 4, 4, 4, 4...
And besides, I noticed that at the end of the array, the numbers are repeated not 4 times as at the beginning, but 3.
...494, 494, 494, 495, 495, 495, 496, 496, 496, 497, 497, 497, 498, 498, 498, 499, 499, 499]
Can anyone explain why this is happening?

firstIterate adds the numbers 0-500. secondIterate adds the numbers 0-500. So, when both of those are complete you have a ThreadSafeCollection with 1000 numbers in it (0,0,1,1,2,2...).  You then combine the results of the two operations, each of which returns the contents of the ThreadSafeCollection so you get (0,0,0,0,1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2...)

Agreed with Paul, but also I cannot reproduce your 3-time repeat. All the values are repeated 4 times as I would expect for the reasons Paul gives. Note that the extra Tasks aren't really helpful useful here, and your functions are marked async when they aren't async. So it's not really clear what you're expecting from these functions.

@RobNapier for example first ends and calls getAll() but seconds isn't ended yet, so the last numbers are appearing just once. Then seconds ends and all numbers are appearing twice now. So in final result will be some items appearing 3 times.

It’s a race. Sometimes you’ll see 499 three times; sometimes four times.

@RobNapier – “your functions are marked async when they aren't async. So it's not really clear what you're expecting…”; it’s likely that he wanted to take advantage of the fact that nonisolated async functions run on the generic executor (SE-0338) and therefore can run in parallel.

Paulw11 explained why you are seeing, in general, four values (because you are appending results to your ThreadSafeCollection, but each task returns the whole, then-current, collection (i.e., returning the whole, combined, collection twice).
And Cy-4AH explained why you sometimes see three occurrences of 499, because you have a race between when one task appends values and when the other task returns the (duplicative) copy of the whole collection. (This problem would be more consistently manifested if one of the tasks was appreciably slower than the other one, e.g., you insert a delay in one of those two for loops.)
There are two solutions:

Given that you are collecting the results in ThreadSafeCollection, do not return the whole collection for each task group subtask. Just return the getAll of the ThreadSafeCollection at the end:
final class ThreadSafeCollectionExample: Sendable {
    var safeCollection: ThreadSafeCollection<Int> = []

    func firstIterate() async {
        for i in 0..<500 {
            await safeCollection.append(i)
        }
    }

    func secondIterate() async {
        for i in 0..<500 {
            await safeCollection.append(i)
        }
    }
}

Task {
    let experiment = ThreadSafeCollectionExample()

    let result = await withTaskGroup(of: Void.self) { group in // or `withDiscardingTaskGroup` in more current OS versions
        group.addTask { await experiment.firstIterate() }
        group.addTask { await experiment.secondIterate() }

        await group.waitForAll()

        return await experiment.safeCollection.getAll()
    }
    print(result.sorted(by: <))
}

That will return the safeCollection with two copies of the values 0..<500, as expected. But this introduces a lot of individual synchronizations, which can impact performance. (See point 2, below, if you want to see how to avoid that.)
Unrelated, but if you forgive me, I tweaked ThreadSafeCollection to use more conventional naming conventions (e.g., append vs add). I also added ExpressibleByArrayLiteral so I could use the more concise initialization syntax. Also, we should probably make sure that T conforms to Sendable:
actor ThreadSafeCollection<T: Sendable>: ExpressibleByArrayLiteral {
    private var collection: [T]

    init(collection: [T] = []) {
        self.collection = collection
    }

    convenience init(arrayLiteral: T...) {
        self.init(collection: arrayLiteral)
    }

    func append(_ element: T) {
        collection.append(element)
    }

    func append(contentsOf elements: [T]) {
        collection.append(contentsOf: elements)
    }

    func getAll() -> [T] {
        return collection
    }

    func remove(at index: Int) {
        guard collection.indices.contains(index) else { return }
        collection.remove(at: index)
    }
}


Retire ThreadSafeCollection entirely, and have the routines return local variables:
final class UsingLocalCollections: Sendable {
    func firstIterate() async -> [Int] {
        var values: [Int] = []
        for i in 0..<500 {
            values.append(i)
        }
        return values
    }

    func secondIterate() async -> [Int] {
        var values: [Int] = []
        for i in 0..<500 {
            values.append(i)
        }
        return values
    }
}

Task {
    let experiment = UsingLocalCollections()

    let result = await withTaskGroup(of: [Int].self) { group in // or `withDiscardingTaskGroup` in more current OS versions
        group.addTask { await experiment.firstIterate() }
        group.addTask { await experiment.secondIterate() }

        return await group.reduce(into: []) {
            $0.append(contentsOf: $1)
        }
    }
    print(result.sorted(by: <))
}

This approach has the virtue of not needing to synchronize each of the 1,000 updates to the collections (which will defeat any performance benefits you hoped for by running these concurrently).



As an aside, going back to your original example, I might recommend avoiding unnecessary unstructured concurrency, i.e., the use of Task {…}.
So, rather than:
func firstIterate() -> Task<[Int], Never> {
    Task {
        for i in 0..<500 {
            …
        }
        return await safeCollection.getAll()
    }
}

You can remain within structured concurrency and simplify this to:
func firstIterate() async -> [Int] {
    for i in 0..<500 {
        …
    }
    return await safeCollection.getAll()
}

And then, instead of:
taskGroup.addTask { await firstIterate().value }

You would just:
taskGroup.addTask { await firstIterate() }

Not only is it cleaner, but by remaining in structured concurrency, you enjoy automatic propagation of task cancelation, etc. Unstructured concurrency gives you more fine-grained control, but encumbers you with the burden of the correctness of the code. So use unstructured concurrency where you really need it (which is not the case here), but favor structured concurrency where possible. It is simpler. (If you really need example of how to use unstructured concurrency properly, let me know.)

Thanks for such a giant and detailed answer, but I have a question. Do I understand correctly, actor guarantees safety and isolates state on some thread, but this does not apply to generic types that are used in the actor and they should be marked as Sendable?

I’d rephrase: Actors guarantee thread safety by preventing two threads from accessing this shared state at the same time, but the idea only makes sense if the type being appended to the collection is also thread-safe, i.e., is Sendable. Or, as The Swift Programming Language says:

“Tasks and actors let you divide a program into pieces that can safely run concurrently. Inside of a task or an instance of an actor, the part of a program that contains mutable state, like variables and properties, is called a concurrency domain. Some kinds of data can’t be shared between concurrency domains, because that data contains mutable state, but it doesn’t protect against overlapping access. A type that can be shared from one concurrency domain to another is known as a sendable type.”
